# XCode 6 - NameError: global name 'ChildProcessError' is not defined

Tags: python, xcode

I've been trying to get XCode 6.1.1 to work with Python. I've got it to build through external build and so forth, however it doesn't seem to find the flac conversion utility, even though I have already installed it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech.py", line 4, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)                   
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 208, in listen
return AudioData(source.RATE, self.samples_to_flac(source, frame_data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 129, in samples_to_flac
raise ChildProcessError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application using brew install flac")
NameError: global name 'ChildProcessError' is not defined
```

Upon using `brew install flac` I get this:
`Warning: flac-1.3.0 already installed`

So I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help me out? I'm a bit confused as to why this is. If I can run this code without issues using Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue... any luck at figuring anything out? I have been able to get it to work by itself with a simple script (see below), but when I link it to a script that's pushed out via Apache, all hell breaks loose...

This works by itself:

import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.WavFile( "1427088466048.wav" ) as source:

```
audio = r.record(source)
```

try:

```
print( "Transcription: " + r.recognize( audio ) )
```

except LookupError:

```
print( "Could not understand audio" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have added API Key ... (Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/#downloads)

API Key

Google Speech Recognition API requires an API key. This library defaults to using one that was reverse engineered out of Chrome, but it

is not recommended that you use this API key for anything other than personal or testing purposes.

Instead, it is best to obtain your own API key by following the steps on the API Keys page at the Chromium Developers site.